# How can I know that this works and is correctly done?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-cleaning, k-nn

**Problem: This seems to be very wrong, cannot pinpoint what I am missing or doing wrong here. Should all rows for each column be Normalized? How?**

I am working on some small thing, and want to get a model that can do KNN and perform: Buy, Sell, or Hold. I download my data from Yahoo, only for a number of stocks or those companies.

The attributes I get back to work with are:

```
Date    High    Low     Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close
```

I then compute, by appending one more attribute: Change, using `df['Close'].diff()`. And then some more preprocessing, `df.dropna(inplace = True)`. I later compute the **RSI** for **Close** price. And compute a indicator: [-1, 0, 1] for either, Buy, Sell, or Hold, based on a Min/Max compared with RSI value.

[image]

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
X = df.drop(columns = ['Signal', 'Date', 'Ticker'])
y = df['Signal']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1, stratify=y)
sc=MinMaxScaler()
train_x=sc.fit_transform(X_train)
test_x=sc.fit_transform(X_test)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1)
knn.fit(train_x, y_train)
knn_pred = knn.predict(test_x)
print(classification_report(y_test, knn_pred))
```

Then, I get the following:

[image]

And when I plot:

[image]

---

*Code as requested*:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_ta as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

def buy_sell_hold(column, window=0, minimum=30, maxiumum=70) -> int:
    if column < minimum or column == minimum:
        return 1
    elif column > maxiumum or column == maxiumum:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0


df['Change'] = df['Close'].diff()
df['Gain'] = df.Change.mask(df.Change < 0, 0.0)
df['Loss'] = -df.Change.mask(df.Change > 0, -0.0)
df.dropna(inplace = True)
df['Adj Ratio'] = (df['Close'] / df['Adj Close'])
df['RSI'] = ta.rsi(df['Close'])
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df['Signal'] = df['RSI'].apply(lambda row: buy_sell_hold(row))
df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True, stratify=y)
sc=MinMaxScaler()
train_x=sc.fit_transform(X_train)
test_x=sc.fit_transform(X_test)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1)
knn.fit(train_x, y_train)
print(f"Accuracy score: {accuracy_score(y_test, knn_pred)}")
```

---

EDIT: I am also doing this,

```
X = df.drop(columns = ['Signal', 'Date', 'Ticker'])
y = df['Signal']
```

Comment: I would suggest putting your original code here. My first guess is you are using Future data (df['Close'].diff()).

Comment: @parvij, what do you need?

Comment: your code which converted raw data to df.

Comment: @parvij Just posted the code

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the signal column based on the RSI and dropping it as a feature for your model, but the RSI data is still a feature to be used by the model. In addition, the signal column is based on simple thresholds which should be relatively easy for a model to predict. Also, you are creating the signal at the moment the final return and RSI are known instead of the day before when you actually want to predict what happens the next day. I think in this case the first two points are the main reason your model is performing so well.

Comment: How can this be fixed?

Comment: Should I shift by a day with `Numpy`?

Comment: **>** *"at the moment the final return"* --- what do you mean by this?

Comment: There are probably multiple ways to solve this, but I would start by either dropping the RSI data as a feature to prevent indirect data leakage or using a different methodology to construct the signal. In addition, you should shift the signal one row back to the day you want the model to actually make a prediction on what to do that day.

Comment: Oxbowerce, why?

Comment: I know that, **SMA20 > SMA50** can be used as an indicator, for telling if price will change tomorrow.

Comment: Take for example the date 29-01-2015, you indicate that the model should perform action '-1' on that day given the available features. But since the day has already ended the model already knows the closing price and return for that day, so it is easy for the model to predict what it should have done.

Comment: Oxbowerce, can you show me, what I have to change in the code I posed?

Comment: Oxbowerce, *"Using a different methodology to construct the signal."*, what different methodology, do you suggest?

Comment: After dropping the **RSI**, I received the following output: *Accuracy score: 0.4401564093845631*

Comment: The fact that after dropping the RSI feature your accuracy score went down significantly is that the model was indeed mainly looking at the RSI feature and was able to relatively easily reconstruct the logic you defined within the `buy_sell_hold` function. This is not unexpected since the logic is simply based on the RSI value and two thresholds, which a KNN model can learn quite easily.

Comment: Oxbowerce, what other problems do you notice here? When you told me to shift, did you mean to `shift(1)` back one previous element, or forward `shift(-1)`.

Comment: Oxbowerce, should I do something more here? Any tips? I am new to this stuff. Thanks so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132242/discussion-between-oxbowerce-and-john-smith).

Answer (score 0):

you have a leaking problam. you are going to predict the signal. Signal shows during the day, not at the end of the day. However, you are using "close", "high", "low" which you just can have at the end of the day.
Imagine the moment you are going to predict the signal, which features you will have at that very moment.

Comment: This doesn't help me at all.

Comment: How can the leaking problem be fixed?